# How to insert a page break in the RStudio Console output?

Tags: r, rstudio

Say I print something which is huge, like str("dataset with 100 columns"). This output is too large to see in one shot. Is it possible to get the output in a page like form where whatever fits the screen comes in one shot then on pressing return, the next batch comes up?

Something like "more" in a linux console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `page` command might do what you're looking for:

```
page("dataset with 100 columns")
```

If I read the documentation correctly, this should call `file.show`, which pipes the data to the default pager (`less` on Unix/Linux systems).

Comment: This opens the output in a browser, I would prefer it happens in the RStudio console as I am using RStudio server with remote access. Even if I use this, str does not store the output in a variable. I asked another question for this,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930292/is-it-possible-to-store-str-output-in-a-r-object